porcelain tile glazing quickly darkens when wet

I am not sure if this is permanent, only happened earlier today. Newly installed rectified porcelain tiles with white glossy glazing. Edges or tiles developed 1-3 cm wide slightly darker region when in contact with wet grout within minutes and does not seem to progress.
Same result when wetting a piece of tile in clean water. I got tiles from different batches and both do the same, only one does it more. Same effect on factory edge and cut edge. Is it possible that water somehow wicks under/in glazing? What is going on?
Tile water absorption specified at <0,3%
More info.
This is what a tile looks like after 2 h of one end submerged in approx. 23 C water:

After that I took it out and placed away. Did not get the picture, but over night the "dry" area shrunk to about 4 cm. In this photo top edge is factory, left and right are cut.
Had a chat with the shop, they have not seen anything like this before, will get in touch with central office on Monday. I still think this is not the body of the tile that is absorbing water but something with the glazing. Can it be that tile has multi-layer glazing and one of the layers is wicking water?

What type of grout are you using?  Sanded or non-sanded?

That’s not something emphasised by local vendors. It is a cement-based grout for indoor/outdoor use. Why are you asking?

Because if the grout line is 1/8 inch or smaller, un-sanded grout should be used. It fills in the grout line with a denser material, (No sand added) .  I was considering that if the wrong grout were used it may allow more moisture to be held next to the tile.   Also with the un-sanded grout a stiffer grout float should be used.  I'm "spitballing" here to help find a reason other than poorly produced tile.

Good question, thanks for the spitball :) Photo shows effects of humidity in the grout itself. Grout is unsanded, very fine.

I have experienced tiles from overseas (being polite here) that have not been fired to the right temperature. They are not really porcelain yet. And they are very absorbent. I have also found that some tiles absorb water from the surface. Because they haven't been glazed properly.
Based on my experience and what I have gleaned from my wife who is a potter.
All you can do now is to let the grout dry and seal the grout.

Tiles are made in Spain, so EU regulations apply.

I would argue that you don't have porcelain tile, regardless of what it says on the box. Porcelain tiles are fired to such a high temperature for so long that they vitrify (turn to glass) and become non-porous. By definition, porcelain tiles absorb less than 0.5% water by weight.
Vitreous or vitrified tile is formed from a wet clay mix while porcelain tile is made from compressed dry powder. Both are equally non-absorbent. A broken edge of either type looks glassy / shiny.
Ceramic tile is also made from a wet clay mix, but is fired at a lower temperature and does not turn to glass. A broken edge looks dull and porous. It absorbs water as shown in your photo.
I think the installer or their supplier have some explaining to do.

No argument here. Gave a sample to the supplier, guys at the store say they have not seen this before.
